Reading and writing multiprocessing postgresql and python
I am  trying to read and write in postgresql database in parallel using python's multiprocessing module. I have two processes, read_database and write_database. I am writing the entries using write_database function (in a loop) and if I see there is an entry of a specific number (in this case its 60), that particular row is read in parallel and some processing is done inside the read_database function while writing is going in parallel. Here's my sample code:
import psycopg2
import multiprocessing as mp

def initialize_database(database_name):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=database_name,
                            user='user',
                            host='host_name',
                            password='password')
    return conn

def write_database(list_id, database_name, table_name, process):
    conn = initialize_database(database_name)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    for i in list_id:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO "+str(table_name)+"(emp_id) VALUES(%s)",
                    (i,))
        conn.commit()
        print(str(process)+ ' writes into the database')

def read_database(num_mult, database_name, table_name, process):
    conn = initialize_database(database_name)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from "+str(table_name)+" where emp_id = "
                +str(num_mult))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    print(data)
    cur.execute("update " + str(table_name) +
                " set emp_id = 1000 where emp_id = %s", (data[0][1],))
    conn.commit()
    print(str(process) + ' reads from the database')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    database_name = 'db_name'
    table_name = 'test_table'
    conn = initialize_database(database_name)
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("DROP TABLE " + str(table_name))
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
    except psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable:
        print('A new table name ' + str(table_name) + ' is created')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS """ + str(table_name) + """(
                ID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                emp_id BIGINT);
                """)
    conn.commit()
    num_range = [i for i in range(0, 100)]
    p1 = mp.Process(target=write_database, args=(num_range, database_name, table_name, 'Process 1'))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=read_database, args=(60, database_name, table_name, 'Process 2'))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

I have following issue:
The data which is a list in read_database is out of range. This is because data is empty which I verified using the print function. If parallel reading works then the emp_id which is 60 should be updated to 1000. Am I missing something?

You're not writing in parallel, you calling write_database which writes sequentially to postgresql in the internal for loop, what you're doing in parallel is read and write, so you could be reading before you've written anything.

@Daviid what I want is to read once that line is written in the database. What I understood is that the entries are inserted and committed in a loop and once my read_database sees there is an entry 60 it reads and updates.

I´m not very knowledgable about multiprocessing but that's what it looks like to me. Bsides there's many things that might be wrong like indentation. Like that conn.rollback()

i removed it conn.rollback()

No, first of all I don´t think you need multiprocessing here at all. You probably want Threads and after you've created the tables needed, launch an infinite loop that constantly checks the table for your expected value. Then you can normally loop and insert data. Once your thread loop sees the value 60 you can make it do whatever.

You should add to your question an explanation of what it is exactly that you want to accomplish, that way people can help you better. I am trying to read and write in postgresql database in parallel using python's multiprocessing module. and what I want is to read once that line is written in the database. What I understood is that the entries are inserted and committed in a loop and once my read_database sees there is an entry 60 it reads and updates seem 2 different goals to me

i have added the details now. Thanks for pointing it out. I guess its clear now.

As I mentioned I don´t think you need multiprocessing (unless you want to do the inserts in parallel and don't care about the insert order)
Here´s how you can do it with threading
import psycopg2
import threading
import time

def get_connection():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="your_database_name",
        user="your_username",
        password="your_password",
        host="your_host",
        port="your_port",
    )
    return conn

def create_table():
    conn = get_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            value INTEGER
        )
    """
    )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def insert_numbers():
    conn =get_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    for i in range(1, 101):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (value) VALUES (%s)", (i,))
        conn.commit()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    conn.close()


def check_table():
    conn =get_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    while True:
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE value = %s", (50,))
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row:
            print("Value 50 found!")
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    conn.close()


def main():
    create_table()

    check_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_table)
    insert_thread = threading.Thread(target=insert_numbers)

    check_thread.start()
    insert_thread.start()

    check_thread.join()
    insert_thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


This starts inserting numbers every 0.1 seconds and checks for the value 50 every 1 seconds.

I did my tests using mysql.connector and I had to add conn.autocommit so it would actually see the values being inserted, you might also need to do that in PSQL
